# Callout: How to add to graphs?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, labeling

## Description of Problem

Mathematica recently added `Callout` as a new labeling option. While I am preferential to using `Tooltip`, if one has to use the image in a presentation, it is nice to have labels. Further, while `Placed` allows one to designate where the label goes in respect to the vertex, I find that it does not exactly do so in a way that is easy to read - especially if some verticies are close together.

## Question

So how can one use `Callout` with `Graph` option `VertexLabels` to get a clean labeling of a directed graph?

Example:

A basic graph

```
simpleGraph = {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 2};
```

Default labels

```
Graph[simpleGraph, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Using Placed works

```
Graph[simpleGraph, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Above]]
```

Using Callout does not work

```
Graph[simpleGraph, VertexLabels -> Callout["Name", Above]]

Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, VertexLabels -> Callout[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, Above]]
```

## Example of Desired Output

[image]

Because this image is wide, we will just zoom up at one part of it

[image]

Ideal:

[image]

I know making a automated label function that minimizes textual overlap with vertices is hard, but hopefully there is a way to at least get text to not overlap.

Sample graph to practice on:

```
exampleGraph={17835 \[DirectedEdge] 17848, 17848 \[DirectedEdge] 20967, 
 17835 \[DirectedEdge] 17845, 17845 \[DirectedEdge] 20967, 
 17835 \[DirectedEdge] 5779, 5779 \[DirectedEdge] 20967, 
 17835 \[DirectedEdge] 3931, 3931 \[DirectedEdge] 20967, 
 17835 \[DirectedEdge] 3870, 3870 \[DirectedEdge] 20967, 
 17835 \[DirectedEdge] 3554, 3554 \[DirectedEdge] 20967, 
 17835 \[DirectedEdge] 3403, 3403 \[DirectedEdge] 20967, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 12657, 12657 \[DirectedEdge] 17835, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 9038, 9038 \[DirectedEdge] 17835, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 5779, 5779 \[DirectedEdge] 17835, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 3870, 3870 \[DirectedEdge] 17835, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 3637, 3637 \[DirectedEdge] 17835, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 3554, 3554 \[DirectedEdge] 17835, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 3367, 3367 \[DirectedEdge] 17835, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 1390, 1390 \[DirectedEdge] 17835, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 560, 560 \[DirectedEdge] 17835, 
 20967 \[DirectedEdge] 482, 482 \[DirectedEdge] 17835};
```

## An unsatisfying approach

Alternatively, a footnote like style would also be ok, e.g. a vertex has a number, and below the graph a table of number name pairs appears...

**Functions**

```
getVerticies[edgeList_] := Module[{vertexList = {}},
  Table[AppendTo[
    vertexList, {edgeList[[i]][[1]], edgeList[[i]][[2]]}], {i, 1, 
    Length[edgeList]}];
  Return[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[vertexList]]]
  ]
makeVertexLabels[vertexList_, labelList_] := 
  Return[Table[
    vertexList[[i]] -> Placed[labelList[[i]], Center], {i, 1, 
     Length[vertexList]}]];
makeEdgeLabels[edgeList_, labelList_] := 
  Return[Table[
    edgeList[[i]] -> Placed[labelList[[i]], "Middle"], {i, 1, 
     Length[edgeList]}]];
```

**Variables**

```
simpleGraph = {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 2};
listOfVertexNames = {"One", "Fish", "Two", "Fish"};
listOfEdgeNames = {"Red", "Fish", "Blue", "Fish", "Octupus"};
```

**Graph**

```
Graph[simpleGraph, 
 VertexLabels -> 
  makeVertexLabels[getVerticies[simpleGraph], 
   Range[Length[getVerticies[simpleGraph]]]], 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  makeEdgeLabels[simpleGraph, Range[Length[simpleGraph]]]]
```

**Table**

```
verticies = 
 Prepend[Table[
   Range[Length[getVerticies[simpleGraph]]][[i]] -> 
    listOfVertexNames[[i]], {i, 1, Length[listOfVertexNames]}], 
  "Verticies"]
edges = Prepend[
  Table[Range[Length[simpleGraph]][[i]] -> listOfEdgeNames[[i]], {i, 
    1, Length[listOfEdgeNames]}], "Edges"]
Grid[{{Column[verticies]}, {Column[edges]}}, Alignment -> Left, 
 BaselinePosition -> Top]
```

Downsides: 
1) I don't know how to guarantee that the vertex numbers fit inside the verticies.
2) nor do I know how to offset the edge labels sightly.
3) Requires more space for publications (because of the table), which means the graph has to be smaller.

Comment: The simple answer is that `Callout` doesn't work with graphs.  You have to implement such a display yourself.  You can write to Wolfram and suggest adding the functionality.

Comment: This is just personal opinion, but I find that your excessive use of headers and boldface harms the readability of your questions.  I could skim them faster if you only highlighted what is truly important.

Comment: @Szabolcs I followed your advise about quesiton layout. So how would one do that....

Comment: It depends on how nice you want it to look ... can you give a mock-up example?  If it's sophisticated enough to make it worth doing, I don't expect it to be easy.  I assume you want more than placing the label in a fixed position relative to the vertex and connecting it to the vertex with a line.  It's a good question, just not easy to implement (in my opinion; maybe someone will surprise us)

Comment: You could make the labels themselves graph nodes and set different styles on them.  Use some force directed layout and try to enforce a minimal internode distance using its options.  Finally verify that the positions are reasonable in the result.  This might be worth a try for certain kinds of graphs.  I am assuming that you don't just want to connect the label and node with a line, but you also want smart positioning (which Callout usually does).

Comment: Can you give an example graph to work with?  I won't be able to make something that works well in all cases, but perhaps something that works for certain graphs is good.

Comment: @Szabolcs adding now

Comment: @Szabolcs as to making the labels themselves graph nodes, that works I guess for a one time rendering if one is sure that they are happy with the final graph, but if one is making a lot of graphs the fine tuning is too tedious.

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry in advance, but I have 2 off (this) topic questions: 1) SparseArray, is there a way to have the value be lists? 2) Place with a good example of making a cloud app / Documentaiton for uploading data, functions etc for the cloud app to use?

Comment: 1) I don't think so.   You can either incorporate the list into the array, or wrap it with some symbol to make it not look like a list. 2) I don't use the cloud stuff ... good place for quick questions is the chatroom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible way is to `ListPlot`  the vertex coordinates of the `Graph` object and `Show` the graph and list plot together:

```
gr=Graph[exampleGraph];

lp=ListPlot[Callout@@@Transpose[{GraphEmbedding[gr], VertexList[gr]}],
Axes->False, PlotStyle->None];

Show[gr, lp]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However ... without finer control on the `Callout` parameters, this is not much better than using `VertexLabels->"Name"`:

```
Graph[exampleGraph, VertexLabels->"Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using labels as `VertexShapeFunction` gives a better picture:

```
Graph[exampleGraph, ImageSize -> 500, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]