# How to use Callout in a directed graph with circular embedding?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, code-request

Given the following code:

```
ClearAll[names, vl, el, ew, community, vName, vRule, g, evc];
names = {
   "agr: Agriculture, hunting, forestry, fishing", 
   "min: Mining and quarrying", "ma1: Food, beverages, tobacco", 
   "ma2: Textiles, textile products", 
   "ma3:   Leather, leather products, footwear", 
   "ma4: Wood & products of wood and cork", 
   "ma5: Pulp, paper, paper products, printing, publishing", 
   "ma6: Coke, refined petroleum, nuclear fuel", 
   "ma7: Chemicals & chemical products", 
   "ma8: Rubber-plastics products", 
   "ma9: Other non-metallic mineral products", 
   "ma10: Manufacture of basic metals", 
   "ma11: Machinery-equipment n.e.c", "ma12: Electrical  
   equipment", "ma13: Transport equipment", "ma14: 
   Manufacturing, nec; recycling", "segw: Electricity, gas,   
   water supply", "scst: Construction", "ma15: Sale-maintenance; 
   repair-install. of mach. equip.", "swhl: Wholesale trade, 
   except motor vehicles", 
   "srtl: Retail trade, except of motor vehicles", 
   "shot: Hotels & restaurants", "str1: Inland transport", 
   "str2: Water transport", "str3: Air transport", 
   "str4: Other supporting-transport act. of travel agencies", 
   "stel: Post & telecommunications", 
   "sfin: Financial intermediation", "sest: Real estate activities", "sbus: Renting of M&Eq and other business activities", 
   "sadm: Public adm.-defence;compulsory social security", 
   "sedu: Education", "shlt: Human health-social work", 
   "soth: Other community, social & personal services"
   };

vl = {"stel", "segw", "ma7", "str1", "str3", "str2", "swhl", "sest", 
   "min", "sfin", "scst", "ma12", "shot", "ma8", "soth", "srtl", 
   "ma15", "ma6", "str4", "sbus", "ma13"};

el = {
   "stel" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "stel" \[DirectedEdge]"ma7", 
   "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "str1", 
   "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", 
   "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "sest", 
   "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "min", "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "sfin", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma12", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "soth", 
   "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl", 
   "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "ma15", "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", 
   "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "str4", 
   "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7", 
   "sest" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl", "sest" \[DirectedEdge] "srtl", 
   "ma12" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", "ma12" \[DirectedEdge] "ma15", 
   "ma12" \[DirectedEdge] "soth", "shot" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", 
   "str4" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", "str4" \[DirectedEdge] "ma12", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "srtl", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str4", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", 
   "ma8" \[DirectedEdge] "str1", "ma8" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "min" \[DirectedEdge] "sest", "min" \[DirectedEdge] "soth", 
   "sbus" \[DirectedEdge] "sest", "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", 
   "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", "ma6" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", 
   "ma6" \[DirectedEdge] "min", "ma6" \[DirectedEdge] "ma13", 
   "str3" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", "str3" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", 
   "ma13" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", "str2" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "ma7" \[DirectedEdge] "ma13", "soth" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7"};

ew = {0.01313, 0.0139, 0.0131, 0.0188, 0.01145, 0.01842, 
 0.01786,0.01203, 0.0137, 0.0188, 0.018, 0.01561, 0.01544,   
 0.01767, 0.0174, 0.0133, 0.0184, 0.0126, 0.01724, 0.0126, 
 0.0139, 0.010414`, 0.0169, 0.01498, 0.01736, 0.01832, 0.01211, 
 0.011911, 0.01586`, 0.01863, 0.01653, 0.01533, 0.0129, 0.0121, 
 0.01144, 0.014, 0.01109, 0.0172, 0.01267, 0.0171, 0.0150, 
 0.01192, 0.01428, 0.017406, 0.0109, 
   0.017892, 0.01338, 0.017794, 0.01095, 0.0187, 0.0155, 0.0142, 
   0.01422, 0.01125, 0.015559, 0.01788};

community = {{"stel", "segw", "str1", "str3", "str2", "sbus"}, 
{"ma7", "scst", "ma12", "shot", "soth", "str4"}, {"ma8", "srtl", 
"ma15", "ma6", "ma13"}, {"swhl", "sest", "min", "sfin"}};

vName = Lookup[Flatten@community]@
   MapApply[Rule]@StringSplit[names, ": "];
vRule = Thread[Flatten[community] -> vName];
g = Graph[vl, el, EdgeWeight -> ew];

ccoord =CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 
Length[vl]][[Ordering[VertexIndex[g, Flatten[community]]]]];

hg = HighlightGraph[
g,
Subgraph[g, #] & /@ community,
VertexCoordinates -> ccoord,
VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", "Circular"], 
EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow[
BSplineCurve[{#[[1]], {0, 0}, #[[-1]]}, 
  SplineWeights -> {1, EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[-1]]]/10, 
   1}]] &), GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide",
VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle"
];

lp = ListPlot[Callout @@@ 
   Transpose[{GraphEmbedding[hg], VertexList[hg] /. vRule}], 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None];

Show[hg, lp]
```

Relevant posts in the MMA repository are

from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/290654/60365 by @halmir

from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140885/60365 by @kglr

The directed graph produced is:
[image]

I want to produce the directed graph with the vertex long names, not with vertex short names such as `stel`. As you can see from the following graph, `Callout` is not working properly.

I like to use `Callout` with long vertex names placed on the right and left sides of the graph vertically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

First, two functions to be used as option settings for `EdgeShapeFunction` and `VertexShapeFunction`:

```
ClearAll[vShF, poincareESF, circleToCoords]

circleToCoords[Circle[ctr_, rad_, {a1_, a2_}]] := 
  Module[{al = Subdivide[a1, a2, 50]}, (ctr + rad {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]} &) /@ al];

GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart;

poincareESF = ReplaceAll[c_Circle :> Arrow @ circleToCoords[c]] @
  GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`geo[0.99 First@#, 0.99 Last@#, "segment"]&;


vShF[assoc_Association, lbls_Association, ps_ : 5, fs_ : .06, ls_ : 250] := 
  Module[{off = If[-(π/2) < ArcTan @@ # < π/2, -1, 1]}, {assoc[#2], 
     Text[Style[Pane[lbls @ #2, ImageSize -> {ls, Automatic}, 
        Alignment -> off /. {1 -> Right, -1 -> Left}], 
       FontSize -> Scaled[fs]], #, { 1.1 off, Center}, 
      ArcTan[#] (-off)], AbsolutePointSize[ps], Point[#]}] &;
```

We use a slightly modified version of `vName` from OP:

```
vName = Lookup[Flatten @ community] @ MapApply[Rule] @
  Map[StringTrim @* StringDelete["\n" | "  "]] @ StringSplit[names, ": "];
```

Use `community` and `el` to get a vertex list and list of intra-community edges:

```
sortedvl = Join @@ community;

internalCommunityEdges = Flatten[EdgeList[Subgraph[g, #]] & /@ community];
```

Define two associations for labeling and styling:

```
lblAssoc = Association @ Thread[Flatten[community] -> vName];

automaticHighlightColors = 
    GraphComputation`GraphInformationDump`$AutomaticColorList;

clrAssoc = Association @ Flatten @ Map[Thread][
  Thread[community -> Take[automaticHighlightColors, Length @ community]]];


Graph[sortedvl, internalCommunityEdges, 
 GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "OptimalOrder" -> False}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> poincareESF, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> vShF[clrAssoc, lblAssoc],
 EdgeStyle -> 
    {e_ :> Directive[Arrowheads[{{Small, .75}}], clrAssoc[e[[1]]]]},
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 ImagePadding -> 180]
```

> picture above

Use  `vShF[clrAssoc, lblAssoc, 5, .03, 160]`, `Arrowheads[{{Medium, .75}}]` and `ImageSize -> 800` to get

[image]

Comment: How can I plot the between community edges on top of the above figure? @halmir developed this code to find the btw-community edge weights `m = Length[community];
member = Association[Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[community -> Range[m]]]];
gedges = 
  GroupBy[EdgeList[g], {member[First[#]] &, member[Last[#]] &}, 
   Total[AnnotationValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight]] &];
{cedges, cweights} = Transpose[
  Flatten[
   Table[If[i != j && NumberQ[gedges[i, j]], {i -> j, gedges[i, j]}, 
     Nothing], {i, m}, {j, m}], 1]
  ]`.

Comment: Something happened to MSE forum and I cannot ask questions on the forum. This is my last resort!

Answer (score 4):

#### 1.

Just use `VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v /. vRule, "Circular"]}` and a large value for `ImageSize`:

```
HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, #] & /@ community, 
 VertexCoordinates -> ccoord, 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v /. vRule, "Circular"]}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow[
     BSplineCurve[{#[[1]], {0, 0}, #[[-1]]}, 
      SplineWeights -> {1, EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[-1]]]/10, 
        1}]] &), GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide", 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", 
 ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

#### 2.

Using `ListPlot` and `Callout`:

```
lp = ListPlot[Callout[##, If[#[[1]] <= 0, Before, After], 
      "LabelVisibility" -> All] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{GraphEmbedding[hg], VertexList[hg] /. vRule}], 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None];

hg = HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, #] & /@ community, 
   VertexCoordinates -> ccoord, 
   EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow[
       BSplineCurve[{#[[1]], {0, 0}, #[[-1]]}, 
        SplineWeights -> {1, EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[-1]]]/10, 
          1}]] &), GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide", 
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle"];

Show[hg, lp]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
nmaps = AssociationThread[Rule @@ Transpose[StringSplit[names, ": "]]];
pchart = 
  PieChart[
   Thread[Callout[ConstantArray[1, Length[Flatten[community]]], 
     Style[#, Bold, 12] & /@ Flatten[community] /. nmaps]], 
   ChartElementFunction -> ({} &), 
   SectorOrigin -> {{-(1.8 \[Pi]/34), "Counterclockwise"}, .01}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
Show[Graph[hg, VertexLabels -> {_ -> None}], pchart, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
sortedvl = Join @@ community;

internalCommunityEdges = Flatten[EdgeList[Subgraph[g, #]] & /@ community];

lblAssoc = Association@Thread[Flatten[community] -> vName];

automaticHighlightColors = 
  GraphComputation`GraphInformationDump`$AutomaticColorList;

clrAssoc = Association @ Flatten @ Map[Thread][
  Thread[community -> Take[automaticHighlightColors, Length@community]]];

g0 = Graph[sortedvl, internalCommunityEdges, 
   GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "OptimalOrder" -> False}];
```

#### GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart

`GraphPropertyChart` combines a graph with a good-looking layout and edge shapes and a pie-chart based on desired vertex properties. It takes both `PieChart` and `Graph` options.

```
 GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[g0, 
  Automatic -> Table[1, Length @ sortedvl],  
  ChartStyle -> Values @ clrAssoc,
  VertexStyle -> Opacity[0],
  EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> clrAssoc[First@e]},
  ChartLabels -> Placed[Values@lblAssoc, "VerticalCallout"],
  ImageSize -> 900, 
  ImagePadding -> {{200, 200}, {Automatic, Automatic}}] //
    ReplaceAll[{Arrowheads[__] :> Arrowheads[{{Medium, .8}}], 
       False -> True, Thickness[_] :> AbsoluteThickness[1]}]
```

[image]

Add the option

```
  ChartElementFunction -> 
    (Disk[Mean[#[[2]]] {Cos[Mean @ #[[1]]], Sin[Mean @ #[[1]]]}, 
      Pi Abs[Subtract @@ #[[1]]]/3] &)
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the codes! In the last two figures above, it might be better to use `Arrow Heads` along the edges so that one can see the actual direction of the edges. Currently, it is a bit difficult to differentiate the edge directions. You do not need to revise the codes, you may just tell me where to change in the codes to get the desired effects.

Comment: excellent point. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!